# Numpy index tuple equivalent of `slice.indices()`

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Given a `slice` object with some of it's defining attributes set to `None`, what it does when used to index into a given list depends on the length of that list. The method `slice.indices()` provides a convenient way to find out what elements are actually selected given the length.

Is there an equivalent function that calculates which elements are selected given a numpy index tuple (possilby containing `Ellipsis`) and the shape tuple of an array (could have more elements than the index tuple), e.g. by generating a full dimensional tuple of integers and slices?